# Compiling SASS using Libsass + SASSC - not emitting SourceMap?

Tags: sass, libsass

I have a setup where I use Libsass + [SASSC](https://github.com/sass/sassc) to compile SASS files (hugely faster than the regular ruby compiler). It is working great, but I can't manage to generate a SourceMap.

The help (./sassc/bin/sassc -h) in the current version of SASSC says that if you want to emit a SourceMap you need to use '-m, --sourcemap' parameters, however a sourcemap is not generated.

I found [this issue](https://github.com/sass/sassc/issues/86) that is marked as resolved, but I have the problem anyway.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Have you set the type of output for the sourcemap?  When I've needed to produce a sourcemap, I've always needed to put the following as a parameter `--sourcemap=file`, which will generate the file.

Comment: When I try this: `/sassc/bin/sassc sass/styles.scss > css/styless.css --sourcemap=mysourcemap` i get the following error: `option '--sourcemap' doesn't allow an argument`. Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: literally `--sourcemap=file`.  You don't change the `file` part.  It's something I had a problem with a while back and made notes on

Comment: I still get the same error message when i just type 'file'

Comment: Take a look at the article I worte on it (http://garybell.co.uk/blog/missing-sass-sourcemaps) and see if that can help.  I don't know if the issue you're getting is because you're not using the ruby compiler though.  Have you tried compiling it with the --sourcemap parameter in ruby?

Comment: Yeah you are talking about the regular sass ruby compilator.  Sassc has different options apparently.

Comment: Shame.  Can you post the compile command you are using so we can see what you're trying and then see if there's an easy solution?

Comment: Here is the compile command `/sassc/bin/sassc sass/styles.scss > css/styles.css -t compressed --sourcemap` I tried different variations of the sourcemap parameters but nothing works

Comment: Looking at http://hongminhee.org/libsass-python/sassc.html, you should be able to do: `/sassc/bin/sassc -t compressed --sourcemap sass/styles/scss css/styles.css`  It's also worth noting that --sourcemap looks like it was added in version 0.4.0 (if I am reading the document right), so which version are you using?

Comment: I'm using exactly this command with no luck :/ I have the latest version, 3.2.5, freshly installed

Comment: @Angel Apparently the command is `sassc <input_file> <output_file> --sourcemap`. Your generated sourcemap file will be `<output_file>.map`.